# StringBuffer vs StringBuilder in servlet filter

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, servlet-filters

i know that in servlet filter we should watch out for thread safty of our instace varibles but in the following code , i used stringBuilder and stringBuffer (one thread safe, one not).

```
public class ValidationFilter  implements Filter {
    //thread safe
   // StringBuffer request=new StringBuffer();

    //not thread safe--lets check if it works fine
    StringBuilder request=new StringBuilder();

////NOTE!!!:even with large request lenght no interference was seen  so what is the problem with NOT being thread safe??

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    //
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {


    //HERE WE PUT SOME CODE REGARDING TO FILTERING REQUESTS
    //HERE WE SHOULD DEFINE A REGEX TO VALIDATE THE STRING IF IT IS NOT THE RIGHT STRING REDIRECT THE REQUEST TO A NEW ADDRESS!!
        //String is immutable so we need to use string buffer or string builder
        //StringBuffer is synchronized, StringBuilder is not. BUT as far as we know Servlet creates new thread for each request fo we
        //need to be synchronised!!

        request.append(req.getParameter("line"));
        System.out.print(request);

      if (request!=null){
          Token.trim(request.toString());
          res.getWriter().print(request);
      }else {
          res.getWriter().print("Error got Null from the client!");
      }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    //
    }
}
```

in both cases i send a really long request using a form as bellow (actually by using this form  i send two really long request inputs) but we i get the out put of the above filter, i dont see any interferece between the output result which means that these two ran thread safly and didnt currupt the StringBuffer or StringBulder , so dose it mean that thread safty dosent mater in this case??

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>a request page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8080/Compute" method="POST">
    Compute it: <input type="text" name="line"><p>
    <input type="submit" value="Compute">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you modifying the state of the filter itself *at all* in your `doFilter` method? That seems like a bad idea whichever type you use. (And even `StringBuffer` is only "safe" in terms of the operations being synchronized - it doesn't mean you can usefully share one instance between multiple *independent* operations.)

Comment: Your entire code makes no sense. `request` will never be `null` so your check is obsolete. If you want to test the return value of `req.getParameter("line")` for `null` you have to do so; appending it to the `StringBuilder` will not turn the `StringBuilder` to `null`. Further you are still passing an immutable `String` to `Token.trim(…)` so the mutability of `StringBuilder` is irrelevant here. Whatever `Token.trim(…)` does, it will not affect your `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

The Only reason you are not seeing any interferece between the output result because [StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) is synchronized, [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) is not. Please note that StringBuffer and StringBuilder objects are mutable which means that the value stored in the String object can be changed.

Since `StringBuffer` is Synchronized, It is safer to use.

Comment: i used StringBuilder also and found no interfernce between output results!

Comment: @user3593084 That's just coincidence.

Comment: See, Both are Mutable so you might not have found it, since `StringBuffer` is Synchronized, so it will be safe to use. Now you might be serving less requests per second. Consider what if there are many request per second, at that time you will defiantly see interference.

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are used in the wrong context. A filter should not be holding state of a request. Operations on `StringBuilder` as already mentioned by others isn't thread-safe. Also as Jon mentioned operations on `StringBuffer` are safe only on individual operations and not on aggregated operations eg. you may end up having `append(...)`'s from multiple threads on the same `StringBuffer` object.